# How to globally cancel post-back events for specific business logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I would like to be able to display a page, but with all controls disabled.  The idea is for a user to view a standard page, but not actually interact with the page.  Disabling all UI-controls server side is simple enough, but my main concern is an "inventive" user attempting to manually post the form back with fake information.  My question is two fold:

1. Will built in event validation catch the devious activities?
2. If event validation doesn't catch it, is there a way to globally throw away the postback event (e.g. the button click, not the full life cycle)

Comment: After a lot of research and confirmations from the SO community, it seems the solution is going to be more complex than initially thought.    It seems the easiest solution will be to add a custom attribute to "naughty" postback sources, query for that attribute during a postback, and redirect to an error page, similar to the suggestion by @dugas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I think to globally cancel the postback is to override this Page method. You can perform whatever logic you need to set the DoNotProcessPostBack during the OnLoad event :

```
Protected Overrides Sub RaisePostBackEvent(sourceControl As IPostBackEventHandler, eventArgument As String)
    If DoNotProcessPostBack = False Then
        MyBase.RaisePostBackEvent(sourceControl, eventArgument)
    End If
End Sub
```

sourceControl is the control performing the postback and skipping over the MyBase.RaisePostBackEvent basically nullifies raising the event for it.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing one of your two questions:

> If event validation doesn't catch it, is there a way to globally throw away the postback event (e.g. the button click, not the full life cycle)?

One option may be to add a value to the ViewState, and if that value exists on a postback, redirect the user to an error page. A user tampering with the viewstate should be caught. This doesn't meet your wish to throw away only the postback event, but maybe redirecting to an error page after receiving a postback from a page you thought no postbacks were possible from is ok.

```
if (ViewState["PageSetToReadOnly"] != null)
{
  // Redirect to error page.
}
```

Another option would be to check if it is a postback in the page's PreInit event, and if so, unwire event handlers:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
  this.Button1.Click -= new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
}
```

Comment: I'm really hoping I don't have to manually alter each event handler, as that would be a very large undertaking.  I'm hoping I can infer state and simply cancel globally.  The business logic is simple enough, I'm just not sure if there's a "solid" way to do.

Comment: Your modification actually brings up a huge hole in my logic, as I really only want to cancel button clicks.  Tab controls, which do issue post backs in order to modify the current view, should be allowed to go through.  I may have to go back to the drawing board on this.

Comment: You can't cancel a button click on a `Postback`. Once the event has fired, you can't stop it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't stop the normal `Postback` process.

How are you determining if the page should be disabled? Upon `Postback` use that same check in your button handler. If it's true, then don't save any information.

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Page is disabled)
    {
        return
    }
    //Do normal save routine
}
```

Comment: That's what I want to avoid. There are tens-to-hundreds of webparts/controls that need to be modified.  All of them inherit from common ancestry which is where I'd like to be able to make the modification.  If I could have something in OnInit that kills any/all pending control event, that would be ideal.